# Very unconfident until I die (riddle)

Tags: riddle

Nightly, to and fro, with I?
Do back and forth to me.
Can you knick knacks with I?
I knack knicks.
Very unconfident until I die.

Hint:

> The bad grammar is intentional and essential in its solution.

Another hint:

> I can't make ends meet.  Maybe you can.

Comment: Maybe wait atleast a day before putting another hint.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't planning on adding a hint for at least a day or two.  I have one final hint that will come.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the answer is

> indecisive

because

> the riddle makes reference to being indecisive with "back and forth" and "unconfident", and most importantly, the answer is spelled out through the first and last letters of each sentence.
>
>  N I / D E / C I / I S / V E

but i can't quite figure out why

> N I and I S are flipped.

Edit diagram:

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer! Could it be the question marks? I notice that the back and forth pattern reverses at the lines ending with ? symbols. Notice, the first line ends in ?, so we switch our perspective (right to left). second line is not ?, so it continues (left to right). Third line is a ?, so we switch again (left to right), and the last two are normal back-and-forth pattern (right to left, left to right).

Comment: i thought about it that way too but i couldn't make sense of the last two lines because i wasn't thinking in a back-and-forth pattern. :P makes sense now though.

Comment: I'm adding a diagram for you. Whether you wish to keep it or remove it, either way is fine with me. :)

Comment: Bravo!! Explanation: the first 4 lines give a hint as to the direction the lines travel in.  knick knacks is a word, so that means left to right.  knack knicks is not a word, but actually somewhat reversed so that meant right to left.  To and fro (go To and Back, right to left) which is the opposite of Back and Forth (left to right).  The last line has no direction markings, only a general hint, read the normal way of left to right.

Comment: By the way, I want also to commend you Bulldogg, on making an excellent diagram.  Thanks!